# Length of "\n" and '\n'

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain to me why `"\n".length` returns `1` and `'\n'.length` returns `2`?

Comment: Read this - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings ...

Comment: I should have thought that actually, how the single and double quotes work in general. I just had in my mind that the double quotes are only for string interpolation and I use single only when I'm 100% sure that my object is a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because backslash escape sequences are not processed in single-quoted strings.  So `"\n"` is a newline (which is one character), but `'\n'` is literally a backslash followed by an 'n' (so two characters).  You can see this by asking for each string's individual characters:

```
irb(main):001:0> "\n".chars  #=> ["\n"]
irb(main):002:0> '\n'.chars  #=> ["\\", "n"]
```

..or just by printing them out:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts "a\nb"
a
b
irb(main):002:0> puts 'a\nb'
a\nb
```

Answer (score 4):

Double quoted strings in ruby are sensitive to escape sequences. \n is an escape sequence for a "newline" character (ascii 0x0A). However, single quoted strings in ruby do not look for escape sequences, so your second string is a literal backslash character, followed by a literal n.